# Keras shape error - im inputting the shape its asking for

Tags: python, json, numpy, keras

I wanted to write a simple function to load a keras model from json and run a prediction. However everytime I run it i get the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking : expected input_2 to have shape (28,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

The code below shows i've printed out the shape of the numpy array and it returns `(28,)`, this still happens if i leave it as a python list.

```
def doit():
    # load json and create model
    json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
    loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
    json_file.close()
    loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
    # load weights into new model
    loaded_model.load_weights("model.h5")
    x = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    z = np.array(x)
    print(z.shape)
    prediction = loaded_model.predict(z)
    return prediction
```

Comment: `z = z[:, np.newaxis].T`

Comment: what a peculiar fix! how does transposing this fix the problem? surely it transforms the input into (1,28)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model has been initialized (and trained) to receive input from a shape (N,28) matrix. It expects 28 columns.

The way to fix this is to reshape your single input row to match:

```
z = z[:, np.newaxis].T #(1,28) shape
```

Or:

```
z = z.reshape(1,-1) #reshapes to (1,whatever is in there)
z = z.reshape(-1,28) #probably better, reshapes to (amount of samples, input_dim)
```